# print cgi fieldstorage object to file instead of a html page python

Tags: python, forms, file, post, cgi

Thanks in advance. I have a dictionary that has been created from form post data. I want to print the contents of the dictionary to another file. I do not want to use it to output to a html page.

```
def cgiFieldStorageToDict( fieldStorage ):
   # Makes a dictionary from the http post data
   params = {}
   for key in fieldStorage.keys():
      params[ key ] = fieldStorage[ key ].value
   return params



my_dict = cgiFieldStorageToDict( cgi.FieldStorage() )
s = open('dict_read.py','w')
z = str(my_dict)
s.write(z)
```

When I open the dict_read.py file I am just seeing an empty dict:

```
{}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually passing fields to your CGI script in the query string (if using GET) or in the body (if using POST). How are you submitting the HTTP request?

Comment: @mhawke Yes I am using post data. I figured out a solution

Answer (score 0):

I could not write to the file because it did not have the right permissions for all users to write to it. I chmod the file to 777 and some of the code and it now works the way I want it too. Here is the code:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
latitude = form.getvalue('latitude')
s = open('any_read.py','w')
s.write(str(latitude))
s.close()
```